# Oozie Subtraction Calculation in Workflow

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm trying to calculate the result of a simple equation in oozie.

Inside config_default.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mintime</name>
    <value>${time - period}</value>
</property>
```

I pass in both -D time=3600 and -D period=3600

I would like the variable mintime to be accessible inside the worklfow with the value of 0.

${time - period} doesn't compute this calculation.

time - this is the number of seconds into the current day the co-ordinator has been run. However as we may want to run this adhoc without a co-ordinator this is specified via -D

period - this is the seconds between each application run, as we want to run this adhoc without a co-ordinator this is also specified via -D

Comment: It will not do the calculation. Oozie does not have any parser for identifying these expressions and computing them.

Comment: From the Apache Oozie documentation: *"Oozie ... provides a **set** of build in EL functions"* i.e. it does not support all of EL features, just a subset. If you want to expose an additional function, such as a "substraction arithmetic operator", then you must implement it in a custom JAR and map it inside your Oozie server config, cf. https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-write-an-el-function-in-apache-oozie/